# Can't find production.log file in my server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am deploying a rails app to EC2 using capistrano and it all works fine.

Except that I cannot find a production.log or staging.log file in the shared folder.

I already ran

```
$ cap deploy:setup
$ cap deploy:check
$ cap deploy
```

And they both work fine.

When I ssh in my instance the log folder in my_application/current/log is empty

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that your are running in development mode ?

Comment: Is your application running? Try called `cap deploy:start`

Comment: I am sure my application is running and cap deploy:start did not solve the problem.

Comment: It's apparently a problem with capistrano as I didn't have the right access to write a create the log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by simply removing all my app on the server and running
    cap deploy:setup
My application was owned by the root user and could not write anything in the log file